# JMM In Practice

Tags: java, multithreading, java-memory-model, happens-before

Consider the following multithreaded code written in Java:

**Shared variables:**

```
         boolean n; // non-volatile
volatile boolean v; //     volatile
```

**Thread 1:**

```
v = true;
System.out.println("n=" + n);
```

**Thread 2:**

```
n = true;
System.out.println("v=" + v);
```

Assume initially `n = v = false`.

Now:

- **Does the output of `v=false` imply the output of `n=true`**?
- *What would change if `n` were volatile?*
- *What would change if `n` were `java.util.List`* (so that `n = true` becomes `n.add("something")` and the output `n=true` transforms into `["something"]`)?
- **UPD3:** What if `v` were `AtomicBoolean` and all reads of and writes to it performed with the `compareAndSet` semantic?

Could you argue your position according to the Java Memory Model?

**UPD:** Please treat `System.out.println("n=" + n)` as just a read of `n`. The same for `v`.

**UPD2:** Could you provide some analysis of the 1st and 4th case as it shown in JSR-133 sec. 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's really three ways that code can execute:

```java
// Thread 1 runs first
T1: v = true;
T1: System.out.println("n=" + n);  // prints n=false

// Thread 2 runs second
T2: n = true;
T2: System.out.println("v=" + v);  // prints v=true
```

```java
// They run in parallel, so assignments first, in any order
T1: v = true;
T2: n = true;

// Print statements second, in any order
T1: System.out.println("n=" + n);  // may print n=true or n=false (depends on CPU caching)
                                   // will print n=true if n is volatile
T2: System.out.println("v=" + v);  // prints v=true
```

```java
// Thread 2 runs first
T2: n = true;
T2: System.out.println("v=" + v);  // prints v=false

// Thread 1 runs second
T1: v = true;
T1: System.out.println("n=" + n);  // may print n=true or n=false (depends on CPU caching)
                                   // will print n=true if n is volatile
```

> Does the output of v=false imply the output of n=true?

No. As you can see in 3rd scenario, `n` may print either value.

> What would change if n were volatile?

As commented, `n` will print `true` in scenario 2 and 3, instead of being indeterminate.

> What would change if n were java.util.List (so that n = true becomes n.add("something") and the output n=true transforms into ["something"])?

This presumes that `n` is already a `List` before the scenarios start, so the volatility of `n` doesn't matter.

Whether the print of `n` will see the inserted value depends on the type of list. If the list of not concurrent, the answer is the same as for question 1: It may or may not see the new value. Examples of non-concurrent lists:

- [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)
- [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)
- [Arrays.asList(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) *(if calling `set()`, since you cannot call `add()` on this kind of list)*

If the list is concurrent, it *will* see the new value. Examples of concurrent lists:

- [CopyOnWriteArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) *(concurrent)*
- [Vector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) and subclass [Stack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) *(synchronized)*
- [Collections.synchronizedList(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList-java.util.List-) *(synchronized)*

Comment: The problem with these kind of analyses is that they completely ignore the allowed reorderings. Yes in a world of sequential consistency this would be correct, but you can't get that one in Java - at least not with volatile. You *can* reorder volatile reads before volatile writes without violating the JMM and suddenly there are a few more possible paths that you ignored.

Comment: @Voo, that is exactly what I want to see. A detailed analysis of the situation as per JSR-133 sec. 8. Updated the original question. (Sorry that initially mentioned Andreas, my carelessness)

Comment: @Kalaider The JSR is long and incredibly formal. Even an informal analysis would take a long time - more than I'm willing to spend. What is easy to say that if you're using a non synchronized list you cannot have a write racing with anything else so for that reason alone it'd be broken.

Comment: @Voo, I share the point the JSR is quite formal and the code analysis based on perhaps the most formal part of it would be extremely verbose. But the more formal the more interesting. Think it's nice to be able to produce the same behavior the JVM does. However, *happens-before* order + program order = enough if one wants to prove the program contains no data races... I'll have to accept Andreas's answer if no one provide more formal explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You have two factors involved here.

- you have a `volatile` field, but
- you have a `synchronized` call to `System.out.println` This acts read/write barrier

In both threads you are performing a write and a read. A write barrier doesn't guarantee a read barrier.

> Does the output of v=false imply the output of n=true?

If you see `v=false` you might see a `n=false` and visa versa

> What would change if n were volatile?

Not really, you might see a change in behaviour depending on the architecture you are running on, however you can still see indeterminate behaviour of some machines.

> What would change if n were java.util.List

The main change is you are replacing a write barrier e.g. `n = true` with a read barrier `n.method`  This means you no longer have a write barrier (except the call to the synchronized method)

Doing this means there is more reasons for consistency between threads to fail.